# Pumpkin Bread that is similar to Banana Bread

Tags: bread

Can you make a pumpkin flavored bread similar to how you can make banana bread? Adding pumpkin to a bread dough mixture similar to how you make banana bread.

Is this what pumpernickel is?

Comment: Banana bread is not banana added to bread dough.

Comment: And neither will result in pumpernickel.

Comment: pumpernickel is a sourdough rye bread.  Banana bread is typically a quick bread, which uses a batter, not a dough.  And you might be able to get a decent bread by replacing  the banana w/ canned pumpkin in a banana bread recipe, but I have no experience w/ that.

Comment: My ignorance put to one side do you think you can make something similar to banana bread with pumpkin?

Comment: @NeilMeyer for the record, I think this is a decent question. Also, I hate it when people think that ignorance has to be punished. I would have posted an answer if I had one, but I have never tried to make anything similar to pumpkin bread. My initial comment was meant mostly as a warning "things are a bit different than what you imagine them to be", so that you can better understand eventual answers, or maybe be able to better specify what you actually want - a "standard" bread with pumpkin taste, or a quickbread with pumpkin taste.

Comment: Pumpernickel is named as it is well because it's "devil's poop". I can't remember the exact etymology, so forgive me for lack of reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is [pumpernickel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumpernickel) a form of pumpkin bread? No, definitely not. Pumpernickel is defined by the grain used (specifically [rye](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rye)) and not by any added ingredients.

Can you make bread with pumpkins? Sure! [Pumpkin bread](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumpkin_bread) is generally a moist quickbread, and like banana bread is often intended as a breakfast food. Unlike with bananas, the pumpkin usually has to be roasted to soften it before use, so it can take a bit more effort (though there is an excellent [instructional guide on the old SA companion blog](http://cooking.blogoverflow.com/2012/10/comestible-orange-goo-making-puree-from-fresh-pumpkins/)) unless you use a pre-cooked canned pumpkin.

The moisture, protein, and fat content of pumpkin (or any squash, really) will also differ from banana, so you are best off *not* substituting into a banana bread recipe. Fortunately, a quick [Google search for "pumpkin bread"](https://www.google.com/webhp?q=pumpkin%20bread) shows dozens of recipes from different sources. Pick one that looks good to you and have a go.

Answer (score 2):

A better analog would be to use a zucchini bread recipe since they are both squashes, however is there a reason why you don't use a pumpkin bread recipe? Pumpkin on its own isn't necessarily the most pleasant flavor. It's the spices that go with it that make it taste great.

If you want a pumpkin like bread but without all the spices you might prefer using sweet potato which has the closest approximation to pumpkin taste that most people expect without needing a pumpkin spice pallet.